# Play Framework 2.1 - Scala - generate forms in code

Tags: forms, playframework-2.0, template-engine, playframework-2.1

I would like to create forms in code, not in a template, so that I could pass just an interface implementation to a template and then call its method like `formHtml`. However, when trying to use the form builders like `inputText` in source code, I get an error that certain implicits are unavailable:

> not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit handler:
>   views.html.helper.FieldConstructor, implicit lang:
>   play.api.i18n.Lang)play.api.templates.Html in object inputText.
>   Unspecified value parameters handler, lang.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Why don't you look at the code that play generates from the templates to figure out where it gets its implicits from?

Comment: How is organized your code ? My test works without any implicit (seems that Lang is provider by "Controler" trait.

Comment: It seems you want to eat the cake and have it too. Either, you use the existing templates or you dont use the form builders in your source code.